# Phonegap blackberry set up Error

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks, phonegap-build

I have a phonegap Application which i have already created in Android,IOS,Windows successfully. But when time to blackberry, i couldn't successful to set up blackberry with phonegap, i have followed the step of set up from phonegap site but i get error from command line and i also try eclipse web work plugin but not found the plugin.

Here i am trying to debug the sample folder which we have in blackberry folder.[image]

i also not found the debug file in cordova blackberry folder.so any one please know the step to set up installation blackberry with phonegap .

Comment: What version of cordova are you using? 
What version of BlackBerry are you targetting (BBOS, PBOS, BB10) ?

Comment: I m using 2.9 phonegap and blackberry 10 webwork

Comment: How did you install cordova/phonegap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Build Projectt :build project :navigate to project folder and cmd
  command : ant blackberry build
- Register with server : blackberry-signer -register -csjpin *123
  -cskpass @123 client-RDK-20***.csj
- sign app : blackberry-signer -storepass *@123 test.bar
- install app : blackberry-deploy -installApp -password @123 -device
  192... -package test.bar -password *@123 ((Navigate to sdk path bin folder under dependency ))
- Ref site :
  http://inflagrantedelicto.memoryspiral.com/2011/02/blackberry-playbook-code-signing-process/

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Cordova 2.9 the implementation of blackberry10 changed from the old one based on webworks to an independent implementation. THe old ant based interface was changed to one more resembling the current CLI. It was split out into its own platform "blackberry10".

Just try running cordova/run from the blackberry10 platform

Comment: i m success to create project in phonegap blackberry ,it also build success the project ..but when try to load-simulator from terminal it failed the build and show errr in blackberry.xml file .         BUILD FAILED
/Users/Glare54/Desktop/blackberry/hello/build.xml:55: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/Glare54/Desktop/blackberry/hello/blackberry.xml:113: /Developer/SDKs/Research In Motion/BlackBerry WebWorks SDK 2.2.0.15/handhelds.manifest.txt doesn't exist

Comment: BlackBerry.xml does not target BlackBerry10 OS. How did you get your cordova/phonegap distribution?